# How can I change the title and factor/level names in effect plots in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, label, effects

As described, I drawed an effect plot as below, and I managed to change the xlab and ylab.

```
library(effects)

eff <- Effect(c("Head_num", "lp"), m.f_alt)

plot(eff,
     ylab = "x_test",
     xlab = "y_test",
     )
```

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiKbF.png)

But now I do not know how to change the the title (i.e., "Head_num*lp effect plot") (and if possible to move it to the bottom).

Neither, I have no idea how to change the factor "Head_num" and its levels (i.e., "S", "P") into any other names. ):

Also wondering if there any possibilty to use ggplot2-likewise function to change the variable/title names.

Comment: `?plot.effects` (after loading {effects}) brings up the help page, where right on top there's a link to the "Predictor Effects Graphics Gallery". {effects} uses another system (lattice) than ggplot2 though.

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggeffects/index.html